# Error with Tensorflow 2.0, Custom Loss Function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I defined a loss function but when I run model.fit() I run into an error which I can not solve.

Here is my loss function:

```
def l2_loss_eye_distance_normalised(y_actual, y_pred):
    #this loss function expects an exact, specific indexing order in the labels

    # the squared, ground truth, interocular distance
    eye_dst_vector = np.array([y_actual[0] - y_actual[2], y_actual[1] - y_actual[3]])
    denominator = kb.sum(kb.square(eye_dst_vector))

    #the squared distance between predition vector and ground truth vector
    dst_vec = y_actual - y_pred
    numerator = kb.sum(kb.square(dst_vec))

    return tf.cast(numerator / denominator, dtype="float32")
```

Later in the main() I compile the model with:

```
model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
        loss=l2_loss_eye_distance_normalised, #custom loss
        metrics=['mae', 'mse']
    )
```

And when model.fit() is called I get an error:

```
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    verbose = 1
)
```

I think that I am making a mistake with the custom loss function but I can't understand what is wrong.
Can someone help out? :)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZxsG.jpg)

Comment: It's unclear to me what your expected output is.  What shape do your y_actual and labels have and what do they mean? Also: is there any standard dataset like MNIST where we can reproduce this with (if so, please add your model, too)? `[y_actual[0] - y_actual[2], y_actual[1] - y_actual[3]]` doesn't do what you think it does (you're indexing the batch dimension)

Comment: Add standalone code to reproduce the error. See [mre] for more information.

Comment: @runDOSrun It seems that the problem is exactly in the line that you pointed out. I am indexing the batches instead of the second dimension. y_actual contains 4 labels, representing the x,y coordinates of the eyes in a picture [left_eye_x, left_eye_y, right_eye_x, right_eye_y]. What I am trying to do is to compute the square of the distance between the left and right eyes (with y_actual). To do this I am trying to subtract the two vectors and compute the norm of the resulting vector. Now the question is --- how can I index the specific labels and not the batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach you would proceed with a while loop in which you would iterate over the batch dimension. This is however very inefficient and unnecessary, as well as more akin to how you would think in python instead of tensorflow. Instead, you should do each calculation for each batch at once. Keep in mind that the loss output is a single scalar (which is why you get that error message "expected non-tensor") so you'll have to eventually sum over the batches anyway.

*Assuming* your shape is `(Batch, label)=(None, 4)` (if you have additional intermediate dimensions, e.g. due to a sequence just add them in all indices below), then you can do:

```
left = tf.math.squared_difference(y_actual[:,0], y_actual[:,2] # shape: (Batch,)
right = tf.math.squared_difference(y_actual[:,1], y_actual[:,3] # shape: (Batch,)
denominator = left + right # shape: (Batch,)
```

From here, everything needs to be of shape `(Batch, )`:

```
dst_vec = tf.math.squared_difference(y_actual, y_pred) # shape: (Batch, 4)
numerator = tf.reduce_sum(dst_vec, axis=-1) # shape: (Batch,)

loss_for_each_batch = tf.cast(numerator / denominator, dtype="float32")
```

Now, how you get a final loss from `loss_for_each_batch` depends a bit on your design but simply accumulating the individual losses would be the normal way:

```
return tf.reduce_sum(loss_for_each_batch)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @runDOSrun ! This solution works and is super lean. Thanks!